# How do I use a `concept` in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I'm wondering how to use a "concept" in nim (0.13). I have the following code:

```
type
  T = concept t
    t.a is string

  T0 = ref object
    a: string

  T1 = ref object
    a: string
    q: string

proc echoT(t: T) : void =
  echo "hello " & t.a

echoT(T0(a: "T0"))
echoT(T1(a: "T1", q: "q"))
```

However, the compiler complains on the first call to echoT:

`t.nim(21, 6) Error: type mismatch: got (T0)`

Shouldn't this work the same as replacing the `echoT` declaration with:

```
proc echoT[T](t: T): void = echo "hello " & t.a
```

(which does compile and run), except that, in the concept version, the constraint
`t.a is string` is enforced?

How do I get the compiler to recognize the use of a concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example compiles and works fine for me (Nim 0.13.0). Is it possible you made a typo in your source file?

Comment: Andrew ... hmm... ok: original does match... but, when I put it in a new place, it works! Something is screwy about my setup in the original place. (nimcache?). Thanks for checking. :)